# Krull dimension of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$

Tags: krull-dimension

Do you have a easy proof of this affirmation:
$\dim_K(k[x_1,...,x_n])=n$ please ?
Cause I found some proofs but they all use others theorems I don't know...
Thank you !

P.S: Sorry if I made mistakes, I am not English but French..

Comment: You might want to give your own ideas, because if you don't, we won't know which proofs you know and which ones you don't... Obviously, it suffices to show $\dim(R[x]) = \dim(R) + 1$ for every ring (maybe domain or some other nice properties) $R$.

Comment: Yes of course this theorem is perfect, but do you know how to prove it ? It is when R in a Noetherian ring.

Comment: There are multiple ways to prove it and you claim that you already know some of them. So as long as you don't state clearly which theorems you know and can use and which you don't, I will most likely also just use things you don't know...

Comment: This is Proposition 11.9 of [these notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/chapter-11.pdf) by Andreas Gathmann.  The chapter is mostly self-contained, but makes some references to other chapters of his notes, which can be found [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/agag/mitglieder/professoren/gathmann/notes/commalg/).

Comment: The result is certainly non-trivial and any proof is going to depend on other results.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of [one of the most famous MSE questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/358423/660).

Comment: Sorry guys I just saw your answers! I'll have a look at it!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @André3000, please could you edit your comment? I am interested, but the link is not available. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Na'omi I think these links work: https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/commalg-2013.pdf https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/en/commalg.php

Comment: @André3000 thank you!